# How to remove security exception from Mozilla & Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, https, ubuntu-14.04, mozilla

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 when where I give any url even gmail.com it is showing "This Connection is untrusted". Its quite irritating for every website I have to add exception & for few of the website Add exception option is also missing.
Can anyone tell me how to remove this exception from my system.

Comment: How about the system date? Is it correct?

Comment: So, as jdloft points out, it sounds like you have a security problem.  A) You may therefore want to raise this on security stackexchange (I would not be surprised if your question gets closed here as being offtopic).  B) I recall there was at least one question on the security stack exchange where it boiled down to someone's country ISP man-in-the-middled all SSL as a policy (but it wasn't India)  C) You may get a hint who is doing it if you look at the root CA for your certificate

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't do any banking or eCommerce through your computer at this time. The errors may actually point at a security hole in your computer.

Now onto debugging. Make sure your computer's date, time, and timezone are setup correctly. An off time could make the certificates invalid by showing that they are expired.

Run `nm-tool` (you may have to `sudo`) and look for the DNS entries. Your DNS should point at a server you know. A 192.168.#.# or 10.0.#.# entry is a DNS server running on your private LAN (most likely a router or switch). If the DNS servers are set to something not on your LAN or Google's DNS servers (`8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`) change them to Google's DNS servers (just to test) by editing `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` (with root) and add

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Now run

```
sudo resolvconf -u
sudo service network-manager restart
```

and test if you are still getting SSL certificate issues.

Answer (score -1):

Mozilla

Go to Tools-->Options-->Advanced-->Encryption.
Click on [View Certificates].
Select the "Servers" tab.
Select the exception to delete.
Click [Delete].